# How do the Apostolic Church install a High priest in light of Hebrews 7?

Tags: priesthood, hebrews, doctrine, aaronic-priesthood

Recently a certain church (Apostolic Church) installed a High priest as the leader of their church

But according to the book of Hebrews the Priesthood of Christ can never be superceded by another priest.

> For he testifieth, Thou art a priest for ever after the order of Melchizedek. - Hebrew 7:17 KJV

In light of the above testimony could any church install a high priest after the advent of Christ.

How do these churches install high priests?

Comment: Could you specify what is the High priest? And provide the link describing the event

Comment: We could benefit with a link to the particular **”Apostolic Church”** you are referring to.

Comment: I expect this is the requested link?  https://zwnews.com/nimrod-taguta-ordained-new-leader-of-johane-marange-apostolic-church/#:~:text=Johane%20Marange%20Apostolic%20Church%20High%20Priest%2C%20Nimrod%20Taguta%2C,family%20from%20his%20late%20father%2C%20Mutumwa%20Noah%20Taguta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak for the reasons the church in the link below would give for installing this man as their High Priest, but the article on the web-page gives a few clues.
I expect this is the requested link?  [https://zwnews.com/nimrod-taguta-ordained-new-leader-of-johane-marange-apostolic-church/#:~:text=Johane%20Marange%20Apostolic%20Church%20High%20Priest%2C%20Nimrod%20Taguta%2C,family%20from%20his%20late%20father%2C%20Mutumwa%20Noah%20Taguta](https://zwnews.com/nimrod-taguta-ordained-new-leader-of-johane-marange-apostolic-church/#:%7E:text=Johane%20Marange%20Apostolic%20Church%20High%20Priest%2C%20Nimrod%20Taguta%2C,family%20from%20his%20late%20father%2C%20Mutumwa%20Noah%20Taguta).

This quote from the article explains something about the process of choosing the successor to the now-deceased former High Priest of this denomination:

> A Taguta family spokesperson, Mr Phillip Taguta said one of the late
> Mutumwa Taguta’s sons, Nimrod, has been ordained as the new church
> leader.
>
> “We now have a new High Priest who was chosen and anointed by our late
> father, Mutumwa Noah Taguta, while he was still alive. He will lead
> both the church and the family just like what our departed father used
> to do.
>
> “Nimrod is one of the late Mutumwa Taguta’s sons. The process of
> choosing the successor takes time and it started long back, well
> before our late father’s fell ill. Nimrod would always accompany our
> father on the various missions they embarked on in and outside the
> country,” he said.
>
> Mr Taguta said Mutumwa Nimrod has been embraced as the new leader by
> the thousands of Johane Marange Apostolic Church members across the
> world.
>
> “All congregants have accepted the new leader and everyone is
> following the dictates of the spirit. Rebellious members will be
> excommunicated just like what happened to Clements Momberume who
> rebelled when our late father was ordained,” said Mr Taguta.

It would require a theologically qualified member of this Johane Marange Apostolic Church to deal with the extremely important fact that God installed his Son, Jesus Christ, as the Great High Priest all Christians have as their Mediator (Hebrews chapter 7). As I have never heard of this denomination until a few minutes ago, I can say no more, apart from express concern at the last sentence in the quote, regarding excommunicating "rebellious members" who won't accept the High Priestly ordination of the new appointee to the post.